# I'll have a or the regular hamburger

Tags: phrases

Which of the following statements is more common in ordering what you want in a hamburger shop?

1) I'll have a regular hamburger and a small French fries.
2) I'll have the regular hamburger and the small French fries.

Any difference between BrE and AE?

Comment: i use 'a' is McD's and 'the' in Burger King

Comment: Why do you differentiate between McD's and Burger King?

Comment: i was joking - i'd never given the Q much thought before

Answer (score 1):

In AmE "a regular hamburger" or "the regular hamburger" are equally acceptable (assuming you mean you want exactly one hamburger.)

But "small french fries" does not need either article. Not only that, "fries" always implies "french fries" in American fast-food restaurants. And a hamburger is often called a "burger".

So it can be condensed to this:

[I'll have a] Regular burger and small fries [please]